# When I open the materials tab -- with Render set to Eevee -- Blender 2.8 immediately crashes

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

Happens every time with render set to Eevee, but not with Cycles or Workbench.

I’m using Windows 7 with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 550M graphics card.

Intel Core i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30 Ghz
64-bit Operating system

Yes, I know that's not such a great system & not a great graphics card.

But other than buying a new computer, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Latest drivers? Otherwise I'd suggest file a bug report.

Comment: Yep -- latest drivers on my graphics card.  Not sure how to file a bug report.

Comment: Go to *Help* (main menu) and click *Report a Bug* - should be self explanatory @gymreading